# Use custom image size in admin panel

Tags: uploads, media-library, media-modal

I have add some image size like:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-small', 600, 600 );
add_image_size( 'custom-medium', 1280, 1280 );
add_image_size( 'custom-large', 2560, 2560 );
```

and I have removed all the default sizes.
Now the Media Library in the Admin panel is loading full image instead of medium.
Is it possible to specify a custom size to use?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to change the default image sizes rather than remove them and add new ones with custom names? The media library uses the thumbnail rather than the medium to show thumbnails and thumbnails image size can be changed using the media settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image sizes are hard-coded throughout WordPress core; [Tom's comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/405223/use-custom-image-size-in-admin-panel#comment591934_405223) to adjust the dimensions of the built-in image sizes is the best approach.